# Get file path in ASP page from code behind to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have a radgrid and a javascript in an ASP page.
This is the script:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ViewCheck(filename) {
        var targetfile = "Allegati/"+ filename;
        var openWnd = radopen(targetfile, "RadWindowDetails");
    }
</script>
```

The above script is supposed to pass the path of a file to a Radwindow and is working fine.
My problem is that for various reasons, I now need now to create subfolders of "Allegati" to store the files separately for each record. Such subfolders are named with the recordID value.
So now the var "targetfile" should be:

```
var targetfile = "Allegati/"+ recordID + filename;
```

In code behind, I get the recordID as following:

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        string recordID = editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("TransazioneID").ToString();
    }
  }
```

How can I pass the subfolder value "recordID" to the javascript in the asp page to get the complete path of the folder containing the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. Let me know if any concern.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OPenPopuP(id, name, serverPath) {
            var targetfile = serverPath + "/Allegati/" + id + "/" + name;
            var openWnd = radopen(targetfile, "RadWindowDetails");
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="ID,FileName">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data1 = new[] {
           new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1",FileName = "jayesh-Softweb.jpg"},
           new { ID = 2, Name = "Name_2",FileName = "jayesh-Softweb.jpg"},
           new { ID = 3, Name = "Name_3",FileName = "jayesh-Softweb.jpg"},
           new { ID = 4, Name = "Name_4",FileName = "jayesh-Softweb.jpg"},
           new { ID = 5, Name = "Name_5",FileName = "jayesh-Softweb.jpg"}
       };

    RadGrid1.DataSource = data1;
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        string strID = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
        string strFileName = item.GetDataKeyValue("FileName").ToString();
        Button Button1 = item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return OPenPopuP('" + strID + "','" + strFileName + "','" + Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath + "');");
    }
    else if (e.Item.IsInEditMode && e.Item is GridEditableItem)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        string strID = item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString();
        string strFileName = item.GetDataKeyValue("FileName").ToString();
        Button Button1 = item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return OPenPopuP('" + strID + "','" + strFileName + "','" + Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath + "');");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to your aspx page.

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfrecordID" runat="server" />
```

And assign the recodId to it in the ItemDataBound event and use it in the aspx page.

```
    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ViewCheck(filename) {
            var targetfile = "Allegati/" + <%= hfrecordID.value %>  + filename;
            var openWnd = radopen(targetfile, "RadWindowDetails");
        }
    </script>


 protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        hfrecordID= editedItem.GetDataKeyValue("TransazioneID").ToString();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is not working, no errors but not working. I think that the variable in the hiddenField is not getting the variable value from code behind because it is inside the method RadGrid1_ItemDataBound.

Comment: @FelliceM - can you check what value is comming in an alert box for <%= hfrecordID.value %>

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually the value is "undefined".

Comment: It is all working. The only think I cannot get right is this.The retrived value for some reason is undefined. I will play with the variables to see if there is a value there when the script calls it. Thanks a lot for now.

Comment: I keep getting undefined even if the value is there (in the variable in the code behind)! Can you direct me on what to check?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37089/discussion-between-bibhu-and-felicem)

Comment: Thanks to you and to Jayesh for the support. At the end I adopted another logic and finally I got it working. However, your support was very helpful to understand the problem.